# Change Output in Table based on SQL Query Result

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to change the printed result in two columns in the table based on whether the column from the sql query is a 0 or a 1

I did an echo of $Status and it puts a list of correct values out, but it is above my table. Am I going about this incorrectly, to place it into my table rows?

The rest of my data populates the table correctly, it is just those two columns. I currently have that portion commented out, and so the output into the table is a 0 or 1 respectively. I also have next to the specific column, a commented out variable of where they would be if they were to be correctly outputting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the portion of the code where I am trying to do the conversion:

```
if ($strAdjIncrease == '0') {
    $AdjIncDec == 'Decrease';
} elseif ($strAdjIncrease == '1') {
    $AdjIncDec == 'Increase';
} else {
    $AdjIncDec == 'Unknown';
}
if ($strAdjStatus == '0') {
     $Status =='Open';
} elseif ($strAdjStatus == '1') {
     $Status =='Closed';
} else {
     $Status =='Void';
}
```

Here is my Full Table Code:

```
if (odbc_num_rows($rsIaL) == 0) {
      echo "<center>";
      echo "<b>We're Sorry, No Records Returned.</b><br>\n";
      echo "</center>";
  } else {
      echo "<p align='center'>";
      echo "<font face='Arial' size='4'><b>Last 31 Days Only</b></font>";
      echo "</p>\n";
      echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='2' style='border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold'>\n";
      echo "<thead>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>#</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>Log ID</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>Reason</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>Inc/Dec</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>Status</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>Ref No</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>Tot Cost</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>Tot Retail</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>Start</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>End</b></font></th>";
      echo "<th ALIGN='LEFT' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'><font face='Arial' size='2'><b>User</b></font></th>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</thead>";
      echo "<tbody>";
      $counter = 1;

      while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rsIaL)) {
          $strAdjID        = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "AdjID"));
          $strReaDesc      = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "ReaDesc"));
          $strAdjStatus    = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "AdjStatus"));
          $strAdjRefNo     = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "AdjRefNo"));
          $strAdjStTS      = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "AdjStTS"));
          $strAdjEndTS     = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "AdjEndTS"));
          $strAdjUID       = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "AdjUID"));
          $strAdjTotCost   = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "AdjTotCost"));
          $strAdjTotRetail = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "AdjTotRetail"));
          $strAdjIncrease  = trim(odbc_result($rsIaL, "AdjIncrease"));

          if ($bgcolor == '#ffffff') {
              $bgcolor = '#dddddd';
          } else {
              $bgcolor = '#ffffff';
          }
          /*
           I can't get this if/else portion to work and output correctly to the table!
           I may be doing it incorrectly though

          if ($strAdjIncrease == '0') {
              $AdjIncDec == 'Decrease';
          } elseif ($strAdjIncrease == '1') {
              $AdjIncDec == 'Increase';
          } else {
              $AdjIncDec == 'Unknown';
          }
          if ($strAdjStatus == '0') {
              $Status =='Open';
          } elseif ($strAdjStatus == '1') {
              $Status =='Closed';
          } else {
              $Status =='Void';
          }
          */

          echo "<tr>\n";
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=center>$counter</td>\n";
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=center> <a href='Inventory_Adjustments_Detail.asp?log_id=$strAdjID&store_id=$storeID'>$strAdjID</a></td>\n";
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=left>$strReaDesc</td>\n";
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=left>$strAdjIncrease</td>\n"; #$AdjIncDec <-if/else variable
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=left>".$strAdjStatus."</td>\n"; #$Status <- if/else variable
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=left>$strAdjRefNo</td>\n";
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=right>$" . number_format($strAdjTotCost, 2) . "</td>\n";
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=right>$" . number_format($strAdjTotRetail, 2) . "</td>\n";
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=center>" . date('n-j-Y h:i:s A', strtotime($strAdjStTS)) . "</td>\n";
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=center>" . date('n-j-Y h:i:s A', strtotime($strAdjEndTS)) . "</td>\n";
          echo "<td bgcolor = '$bgcolor' align=left>$strAdjUID</td>\n";
          echo "</tr>";
          $counter++;
      }

      echo "</tbody>\n";
      echo "</table><br>\n";

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I don't understand your code very well... but here are some thoughts:

1. try echo-ing your variables `$strAdjIncrease` and `$strAdjStatus` before the if/else-statement to test what values they have - debug. maybe the error is somewhere up the line.
2. i don't know if that's a typo or what you're trying to do but I believe
   `$AdjIncDec == 'Increase';` (and other variables) inside your if/else-statements shouldn't have double equals `==` but single `=`!?
3. try `===` instead of `==` in your if/else-statement.

Comment: I know this question isn't about style and maybe that's not even your own code you're working on there, but it is cleaner to just close the php tags write some html and open the php tags again instead of echo-ing tons of lines. e.g. `... ?> <p>some html here and output a <?php echo $variable; ?> and more html there </p> <?php ...`. And there is a lot of (deprecated) HTML-styling where you should actually use CSS... no offence, just some advice :)

Comment: Yeah its not my code. It is something at my work that I am trying to fix/get working. The code is for an internal employee intranet and the head guy doesn't care about CSS/Formatting for employees. Since it is all mostly just reports they are looking at. It is just a page with a heading and a report. He said once everything works, then we will worry about making the code look good/format with css.

Comment: I made the changes in my If/else-statement that you proposed and it is now working. Thank you very much! As you can tell I am fairly new to PHP and I am still learning something new every day. For example, I didn't know you could use ===. I thought it was just == or =. 

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: you're welcome! I'm happy i could help. Yeah the `===` also checks on the data-type... so it's safer if you don't just want to compare 2 strings (words) but actually want to validate if a expression is `true` or `false` - then always use `===`. maybe you want to look into [type-juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [cast boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)